# How to insert array values in Mysql database using java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

What i want insert these values in one field of mysql database :

```
String[] content = {"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"};
aArray
...?//how can i write the code here..help me 


String query = "insert into CHAR_ARRAY_TABLE(id, cont) values(?,?)";

preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

preparedStatement.setInt(1, row_id_name);
preparedStatement.setArray(2, aArray);
int count = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
System.out.println(count + " inserted");
```

Comment: Do you want to insert value of Array element as single String in column `con`?

Answer (score 0):

Iam using this way to insert data into my SQL from Java using MySQL Connector 8.0.23.jar

First the array:

```
Connection conexion = null;
Statement instr = null;
ResultSet contenido = null;
public static String datosEnviar [][] = 
    {   {"Tierra",  "Rocoso",   "6371"},
        {"Jupiter", "Gaseoso",  "71492"},
        {"Urano",   "Helado",   "28709"},
        {"Mercurio",    "Rocoso",   "2440"},
    };
```

Second the way i insert data into MySQL.

```
public void Insertar()
{   String comando = "insert into tablaPiramides (id, planeta, tipo, radio)"
                    +" values (?,?,?,?)";
    ResultSetMetaData datos;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    int nc=0;
    try {
        datos = contenido.getMetaData();
        nc = datos.getColumnCount();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    PreparedStatement declaracion;
    
    try {
        declaracion = conexion.prepareStatement(comando);
        for (int nId=1; nId<=4; nId++) {
            declaracion.setInt(1, nId);
            
            for (int c=0; c<3; c++) {
                declaracion.setString(c+2, datosEnviar[nId-1][c]);
            } declaracion.executeUpdate();
        }
        //declaracion.execute();
        
        
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I hope it can help you in the second method, iam using a double for one for ids, and a second f for insert data each column `declaracion.setString(c+2, datosEnviar[nId-1][c]);`

Answer (score 0):

To insert an array of strings into a single field in a MySQL database using Java, you need to convert the array into a format that MySQL can store in a single field. MySQL doesn't support storing arrays directly, so you typically need to convert the array into a string representation. One common method is to join the array elements into a single string, with a delimiter separating each element.

```
String[] content = {"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"};
String joinedContent = String.join(",", content); // Joining array elements with a comma

String query = "INSERT INTO CHAR_ARRAY_TABLE(id, cont) VALUES(?, ?)";

preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, row_id_name);
preparedStatement.setString(2, joinedContent); // Set the joined string
int count = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
System.out.println(count + " records inserted");
```