# JDBC for array (or list) values determined at run time

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am looking at this post [How to insert array values in Mysql database using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42018694/how-to-insert-array-values-in-mysql-database-using-java) with keen interest. But just to get started I find that MySQL Workbench rejects the indicated sql statements for table creation and update(insert).

I ended up loading a single line dataframe from R into my MySQL demo database to create table itemtable. This is not ideal since the item values are intended to be integers, but loading like this from R creates the fields as double.

itemtable fields are "time", "item1", "item2", "duration"
initial line values are 0.0, 1, 1, 0.0

I created an Item class:

```java
public class Item {
    String name;
    double value;   
    public Item(String name, double value)  {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
```

In my real application Items are far more complex and value is calculated at different times. So I use a LinkedList to hold these. The quantity of items is variable from model to model as an input of other data tables just as I did from R.

The full test code - That works!!! as follows:

```java
public class Item {
    String name;
    double value;   
    public Item(String name, double value)  {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
 
public class ItemTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException  {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;        
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?useSSL=false";
        String user = "student";
        String pass = "student";
        LinkedList<Item> itemList = new LinkedList<>();
        itemList.add(new Item("item1", 0.0));
        itemList.add(new Item("item2", 1.0));
        double timeNow = 30.0;
        double duration = 0.0;
        String qMarks = "";
        String names = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
            qMarks = qMarks + "?,";
            names = names + itemList.get(i).name + ",";
        }
        System.out.println(qMarks);
        System.out.println(names);
        String pquery = "insert into itemtable(time," + names +
                "duration) values(?," + qMarks + "?)";
        System.out.println(pquery);
   
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo", "student" , "student");
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(pquery);
            pstmt.setDouble(1, timeNow);
            for(int i = 0; i<itemList.size(); i++) {
                pstmt.setDouble(i+2, itemList.get(i).value);
            }
            pstmt.setDouble(itemList.size()+2, duration);
            int count = pstmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(count + " inserted");
              
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from itemtable");
            while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getDouble("time") + ", " + rs.getDouble("item1"));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException exc){            
        }
        finally {
            if (rs != null) rs.close();            
            if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
            if (conn != null) conn.close();
        }       
    }
}
```

Full verification of the table insert is confirmed in MySQL Workbench.

It would still be nice if I could create the itemtable from within java code.

Comment: Please provide more information. What sql statements to you use? What errors do you get?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support ARRAY as datatype. That's why no matter how hard you try, you won't get the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

As the linked SO post tells you: SQL's 'ARRAY' concept (which is mirrored by JDBC's .setArray and .getArray and java.sql.Array) just doesn't work in mysql. At all.

I suggest you use a better DB engine, such as postgres. Otherwise, well, you can't have arrays; what you can try to do is make a table to represent it. The usual many-to-one stuff in DBs: Instead of 'an array', you have a second table containing 1 row for each 'slot' in all arrays across the entire dataset: Each row in this 'array table' contains the data as well as a reference.

So, for example:

```
-- This works in PSQL:
CREATE TABLE example (id integer, whatever text, names text[], PRIMARY KEY(id));
-- but the above does not work in MySQL, so there do e.g.:

CREATE TABLE example (id integer, whatever text, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE TABLE example_names (id integer, example_id integer, name text, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE INDEX example_names_lnk ON example_names(example_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that what I was trying to do with the list item with quantity defined at runtime was indeed different than trying to enter an array in a MySQL table, which I now understand cannot be done. I do appreciate the earlier discussion, which sparked my interest in solution I needed.

The create table sql is generated in a straight forward way, the key to handling the unknown content at runtime was to build the query string using a loop for the item columns. A single loop built internal string items for the create statement as well as the prepared statements.

So the sql for creating the table in java code is straight forward. Item values can now be integers as intended.

```
        String qMarks = "";
        String names = "";
        String items = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
            qMarks = qMarks + "?,";
            names = names + itemList.get(i).name + ",";
            items = items + itemList.get(i).name +" INTEGER,";
        }
        String createsql = "CREATE TABLE ITEMTABLE (" +
                            "time DOUBLE, " + items +
                            "duration DOUBLE)";
```